# How to access/inject a sessionscoped bean from an EJB's asynchronous method?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, cdi

I have a sessionscoped bean holding e.g. a current shopping cart and user contact data. At some point the user is redirected to payment provider and then back to my page. As I do not want to delay the return to my page, I invoke the business methods that happen on page load asynchronously, block the UI and display some "busy messages".
That works fine so far. The Problem is: I would like the asynchronous methods to read and process data from the above mentioned session scoped bean (user's contact data to order a deliverer) and if something fails go back some steps and still have the session data (shopping cart etc.) available and log the error into a log in the session scoped bean.
But since I can not use an injected bean in an `@Asynchronous`-annotated method I am clueless how to do that.

Comment: You can't.  The scope does not propogate to async methods.

Comment: @JohnAment You should move your comment to an answer. If you have any suggestions for how OP could accomplish the task differently (e.g., storing state in a separate object accessible from the session scope, and then explicitly pass it to the async method?), that would also be good.

Comment: I prefer answers to be "this is how you do it" not "you can't do that."  This is an explicit limitation.  It should be pretty obvious that you can pass in arguments to the method that they may need, but you'll run in to scope issues regardless.

Comment: @JohnAment, why isn't the scope propagated? According to [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/context/RequestScoped.html) the request scope is active "during any asynchronous method invocation of any EJB". Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work with GF 3, GF 4 and Wildfly 8.2 (I've tried it myself). Lester: I've read about [another (less appealing) approach](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/how_to_pass_context_in) which I didn't try yet. Maybe this is helpful in your case...